# Array Object multiply and final sum in node JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I need to perform a calculation on array of objects

```
sum of each row = sum of costs * quantity
total = sum of (sum of each row)
```

Here is my array object

```
const newArray = [
{ 'LOA Qty': '2000', 'Labour Cost': '118', 'Labour Cost': '118' },  // (118 + 118) * 2000  = 236118
{ 'LOA Qty': '300', 'Ma Cost': '59', 'Cost one': '118' }, // (59 + 118) * 300 = 35459
{ 'LOA Qty': '4', 'sdf Cost': '16520', 'Cost tow': '118' }]; // (16520 + 118) * 4 = 16992
```

Total sum will be

```
236118 + 35459 + 16992 = 288569
```

Here is the logic i have written

```
let estimatedBudget = 0;

newArray.forEach(element => {
    for (var el in element) {
        if (element.hasOwnProperty(el)) {
            estimatedBudget += parseFloat(element[el]);
        }
    }
    return estimatedBudget;
 });
```

Comment: Hi, you have this property 'Labour Cost' repeated in the first item, that will affect the final result

Comment: Why do you never attempt to multiply your item sum with the value in "LOA Qty"?

Comment: @RobC, his math is blowing my mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are getting numbers as strings then it should be helpful for you.

```js
const newArray = [
{ 'LOA Qty': '2000', 'Labour Cost': '118', 'sdg Cost': '118' },
{ 'LOA Qty': '300', 'Ma Cost': '59', 'Cost one': '118' },
{ 'LOA Qty': '4', 'sdf Cost': '16520', 'Cost tow': '118' }];

function getSum(item) {
    const keys = Object.keys(item).filter(f => f !== 'LOA Qty');
    return keys.reduce((sum, current) => +sum + +item[current], 0);
}

console.log(newArray.reduce((sum, current) => sum + (getSum(current) * +current['LOA Qty']), 0));
```

**Calculation:**

(118+118) * 2000 = 472000

(59+118) * 300 = 53100

(16520+118) * 4 = 66552

472000 + 53100 + 66552 = **591652**